# XSLT Counters Recursion and Passing Parameters

Tags: xslt, recursion, parameters, counter

I have been able to create an XSLT (included) to convert a source XML to a target desired XML format (included), however I am sure this can be optimized leveraging some built in XSLT capabilities which are beyond my proficiency. Appreciate any thoughts.

The core requirement is that Input XML contains header values and data (the first record contains the header/labels and subsequent records contain data for those respective label, hence output data is positionally matched with the first record), OutPut XML contains Name Value Pairs, the name describes the data element (header/label from 1st record in the source) and the elements are "labelXX","valueXX", hence the need for counters to increment XX. The output also contains a header record which essentially just contains the name of the element, rest is self explanatory from the output.

Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SpecExportFF>
 <recordset>
<value>12345</value>
<value>xyz</value>
    <value>a0</value>
    <value>b0</value>
    <value>c0</value>
    <value>d0</value>
    <value>e0</value>
    <value>f0</value>
    <value>g0</value>
    <value>h0</value>
    <value>i0</value>
    <value>j0</value>
    <value>k0</value>
    <value>l0</value>
    <value>m0</value>
    <value>n0</value>
    <value>o0</value>
    <value>p0</value>
    <value>q0</value>
    <value>r0</value>
    <value>s0</value>
    <value>t0</value>
    <value>a1</value>
    <value>b1</value>
    <value>c1</value>
    <value>d1</value>
    <value>e1</value>
    <value>f1</value>
    <value>g1</value>
    <value>h1</value>
    <value>i1</value>
    <value>j1</value>
    <value>k1</value>
    <value>l1</value>
    <value>m1</value>
    <value>n1</value>
    <value>o1</value>
    <value>p1</value>
    <value>q1</value>
    <value>r1</value>
    <value>s1</value>
    <value>t1</value>
    <value>a2</value>
    <value>b2</value>
    <value>c2</value>
    <value>d2</value>
    <value>e2</value>
    <value>f2</value>
    <value>g2</value>
    <value>h2</value>
    <value>i2</value>
    <value>j2</value>
    <value>k2</value>
    <value>l2</value>
    <value>m2</value>
    <value>n2</value>
    <value>o2</value>
    <value>p2</value>
    <value>q2</value>
    <value>r2</value>
    <value>s2</value>
    <value>t2</value>
 </recordset>
 <recordset>
    <value>A12345</value>
    <value>snacks</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>cereals</value>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
 </recordset>
 <recordset>
    <value>A245678</value>
    <value>snacks</value>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>chips</value>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value>potato</value>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value>fried</value>
    <value/>
    <value></value>
    <value/>
    <value>baked</value>
    <value></value>
    <value></value>
    <value></value>
    <value/>
    <value></value>
    <value/>
    <value>20g</value>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value/>
    <value></value>
 </recordset>
</SpecExportFF>
```

Output Target XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SpecExportOutputFF>
    <header>
       <item>item</item>
       <category>category</category>
       <label01>label01</label01>
       <spec01>spec01</spec01>
       <label02>label02</label02>
       <spec02>spec02</spec02>
       <label03>label03</label03>
       <spec03>spec03</spec03>
       <label04>label04</label04>
       <spec04>spec04</spec04>
       <label05>label05</label05>
       <spec05>spec05</spec05>
       <label06>label06</label06>
       <spec06>spec06</spec06>
       <label07>label07</label07>
       <spec07>spec07</spec07>
       <label08>label08</label08>
       <spec08>spec08</spec08>
       <label09>label09</label09>
       <spec09>spec09</spec09>
       <label10>label10</label10>
       <spec10>spec10</spec10>
       <label11>label11</label11>
       <spec11>spec11</spec11>
       <label12>label12</label12>
       <spec12>spec12</spec12>
       <label13>label13</label13>
       <spec13>spec13</spec13>
       <label14>label14</label14>
       <spec14>spec14</spec14>
       <label15>label15</label15>
       <spec15>spec15</spec15>
       <label16>label16</label16>
       <spec16>spec16</spec16>
       <label17>label17</label17>
       <spec17>spec17</spec17>
       <label18>label18</label18>
       <spec18>spec18</spec18>
       <label19>label19</label19>
       <spec19>spec19</spec19>
       <label20>label20</label20>
       <spec20>spec20</spec20>
       <label21>label21</label21>
       <spec21>spec21</spec21>
       <label22>label22</label22>
       <spec22>spec22</spec22>
       <label23>label23</label23>
       <spec23>spec23</spec23>
       <label24>label24</label24>
       <spec24>spec24</spec24>
       <label25>label25</label25>
       <spec25>spec25</spec25>
       <label26>label26</label26>
       <spec26>spec26</spec26>
       <label27>label27</label27>
       <spec27>spec27</spec27>
       <label28>label28</label28>
       <spec28>spec28</spec28>
       <label29>label29</label29>
       <spec29>spec29</spec29>
       <label30>label30</label30>
       <spec30>spec30</spec30>
       <label31>label31</label31>
       <spec31>spec31</spec31>
       <label32>label32</label32>
       <spec32>spec32</spec32>
       <label33>label33</label33>
       <spec33>spec33</spec33>
       <label34>label34</label34>
       <spec34>spec34</spec34>
       <label35>label35</label35>
       <spec35>spec35</spec35>
       <label36>label36</label36>
       <spec36>spec36</spec36>
       <label37>label37</label37>
       <spec37>spec37</spec37>
       <label38>label38</label38>
       <spec38>spec38</spec38>
       <label39>label39</label39>
       <spec39>spec39</spec39>
       <label40>label40</label40>
       <spec40>spec40</spec40>
       <label41>label41</label41>
       <spec41>spec41</spec41>
       <label42>label42</label42>
       <spec42>spec42</spec42>
       <label43>label43</label43>
       <spec43>spec43</spec43>
       <label44>label44</label44>
       <spec44>spec44</spec44>
       <label45>label45</label45>
       <spec45>spec45</spec45>
       <label46>label46</label46>
       <spec46>spec46</spec46>
       <label47>label47</label47>
       <spec47>spec47</spec47>
       <label48>label48</label48>
       <spec48>spec48</spec48>
       <label49>label49</label49>
       <spec49>spec49</spec49>
       <label50>label50</label50>
       <spec50>spec50</spec50>
       <label51>label51</label51>
       <spec51>spec51</spec51>
       <label52>label52</label52>
       <spec52>spec52</spec52>
       <label53>label53</label53>
       <spec53>spec53</spec53>
       <label54>label54</label54>
       <spec54>spec54</spec54>
       <label55>label55</label55>
       <spec55>spec55</spec55>
       <label56>label56</label56>
       <spec56>spec56</spec56>
       <label57>label57</label57>
       <spec57>spec57</spec57>
       <label58>label58</label58>
       <spec58>spec58</spec58>
       <label59>label59</label59>
       <spec59>spec59</spec59>
       <label60>label60</label60>
       <spec60>spec60</spec60>
    </header>
    <data>
       <item>A12345</item>
       <category>snacks</category>
       <label01>a0</label01>
       <spec01>1</spec01>
       <label02>b0</label02>
       <spec02>cereals</spec02>
    </data>
    <data>
       <item>A245678</item>
       <category>snacks</category>
       <label01>a0</label01>
       <spec01>1</spec01>
       <label02>b0</label02>
       <spec02>chips</spec02>
       <label03>q0</label03>
       <spec03>potato</spec03>
       <label04>e1</label04>
       <spec04>fried</spec04>
       <label05>i1</label05>
       <spec05>baked</spec05>
       <label06>p1</label06>
       <spec06>20g</spec06>
    </data>
    </SpecExportOutputFF>
```

My XSLT (It works but is too complicated in my opinion and would like to optimize it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/SpecExportFF">
        <SpecExportOutputFF>
            <xsl:for-each select="recordset">
                <xsl:variable name="IndexOfCurrentRecordset">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$IndexOfCurrentRecordset = 1">
                    <header>
                        <xsl:for-each select="value">
                            <xsl:variable name="IndexOfCurrentNode" select="position()"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="ElementSuffix" select="format-number(($IndexOfCurrentNode - 2),'00')"/>
                            <!--<hello1><xsl:value-of select="$IndexOfCurrentNode"/></hello1>-->
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$IndexOfCurrentNode = 1">
                                    <xsl:element name="item">item</xsl:element>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$IndexOfCurrentNode = 2">
                                    <xsl:element name="category">category</xsl:element>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="($IndexOfCurrentNode > 2)">
                                    <xsl:element name="{concat('label',$ElementSuffix)}">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('label',$ElementSuffix)"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                    <xsl:element name="{concat('spec',$ElementSuffix)}">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('spec',$ElementSuffix)"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </header>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$IndexOfCurrentRecordset > 1">
                    <data>
                        <xsl:call-template name="iterate_values">
                            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="1"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="./value[1]"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentRecordset" select="$IndexOfCurrentRecordset"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentNode" select="1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </data>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </SpecExportOutputFF>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="iterate_values">
        <xsl:param name="i"/>
        <xsl:param name="currentNode"/>
        <xsl:param name="IndexOfCurrentRecordset"/>
        <xsl:param name="IndexOfCurrentNode"/>

        <xsl:variable name="ElementSuffix" select="format-number($i,'00')"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$IndexOfCurrentNode = 1">
                <xsl:element name="item">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currentNode/text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:if test="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="iterate_values">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentRecordset" select="$IndexOfCurrentRecordset"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentNode" select="$IndexOfCurrentNode+1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$IndexOfCurrentNode = 2">
                <xsl:element name="category">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currentNode/text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:if test="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="iterate_values">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentRecordset" select="$IndexOfCurrentRecordset"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentNode" select="$IndexOfCurrentNode+1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$IndexOfCurrentNode > 2 and $currentNode/text() != ''">
                <xsl:element name="{concat('label',$ElementSuffix)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="/*/*[1]/value[$IndexOfCurrentNode]"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="{concat('spec',$ElementSuffix)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$currentNode/text()"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:if test="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="iterate_values">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i+1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentRecordset" select="$IndexOfCurrentRecordset"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentNode" select="$IndexOfCurrentNode+1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="iterate_values">
                        <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="currentNode" select="/SpecExportFF/recordset[position() = $IndexOfCurrentRecordset]/value[position() = $IndexOfCurrentNode+1]"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentRecordset" select="$IndexOfCurrentRecordset"/>
                            <xsl:with-param name="IndexOfCurrentNode" select="$IndexOfCurrentNode+1"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: A better place to ask this type of question is on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, will post there as well.

Comment: Why don't you explain the required logic in words?

Comment: added additional comments. thx

Comment: That's not what I asked for. I am not interested in reviewing your code (TL, DR). I might be able to suggest an alternative approach - if I knew the purpose of this exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the challenge, I worked out what it looks like you are trying to do. I think the main issue is you are thinking imperatively, but need to switch your mindset because XSLT is a functional language, and things are very different.

Indeed, this is what I came up with...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="labels" select="/SpecExportFF/recordset[1]/value[position() > 2]" />

  <xsl:template match="SpecExportFF">
    <SpecExportOutputFF>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="recordset" />
    </SpecExportOutputFF>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recordset[1]">
    <header>
     <item>item</item>
     <category>category</category>
     <xsl:for-each select="value">
     </xsl:for-each> 
    </header>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recordset[1]">
    <header>
     <item>item</item>
     <category>category</category>
     <xsl:for-each select="value[position() > 2]">
       <xsl:variable name="ElementSuffix" select="format-number(position(),'00')"/>
       <xsl:element name="{concat('label',$ElementSuffix)}">
         <xsl:value-of select="concat('label',$ElementSuffix)"/>
       </xsl:element>
       <xsl:element name="{concat('spec',$ElementSuffix)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('spec',$ElementSuffix)"/>
       </xsl:element>
     </xsl:for-each> 
    </header>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="recordset">
     <data>
       <item><xsl:value-of select="value[1]" /></item>
       <category><xsl:value-of select="value[2]" /></category>
       <xsl:for-each select="value[position() > 2][normalize-space()]">
            <xsl:variable name="ElementSuffix" select="format-number(position(),'00')"/>
            <xsl:variable name="LabelPos" select="count(preceding-sibling::value) - 1" />
            <xsl:element name="{concat('label',$ElementSuffix)}">
              <xsl:value-of select="$labels[position() = $LabelPos]" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="{concat('spec',$ElementSuffix)}">
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks [Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7585/tim-c), I am still working on readjusting my brain to fit XSLT ;) but your solution is definitely way more elegant. However the output XML generated by your XSL is is missing label values which have to be positionally matched to the values in the 1st recordset of the input XML.

Comment: Thanks Tim, was a mistake on my end, your solution works perfectly, thanks.